# How do I display/see the Valid List in a Google spreadsheet on Android device?

Tags: google-drive

I made a spreadsheet in Google Docs and used data validation to restrict a range of cells to a list of valid values. When I look at the spreadsheet using a browser, the valid list is correctly shown in the dropdown menu. However, when I look at the spreadsheet in my Android phone, I don't see the list (there is a little [1] shown in the cell, but I don't see how to click this.)

Is there any way to make this list display on a phone?

Comment: Just to clarify, is this being viewed on the phone via the Google Drive (formerly Google Docs) app?

Comment: yes. i haven't tried it on an iphone yet, but i'd hope the same solution works there as well.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Google Drive App I created a test spreadsheet to investigate your question. I found the `[1]` to be a footnote - at the bottom of the spreadsheet is a list of all notes about validation for each applicable cell. The same applies to comments made to cells and, I suspect, other types of advanced cell formatting that don't translate well to small screens. It's clunky, but at least the validation follows to mobile. There doesn't seem to be a way to change how validation information is displayed.

See here below the spreadsheet are two footnotes, one indicating valid data (by displaying the help text, `[1]`) and the other representing invalid data (by displaying "validationFailed[Help Text]," `[2]`):

[image]